# PHP leading zero beginning with 01 not 00

Tags: php, wordpress, count, numbers

I am using the following PHP in a wordpress theme for comment count...

```
   <?php $i = 0; foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>       

   <?php $ii = sprintf("%02d", $i);?>

   <?php $i++;echo $ii; echo '.&ensp;';?>
```

(Echo the comment number beginning with `01.`)

The problem is that the first comment starts with `00.` instead of `01.`

Example:

```
00. John Smith says...

01. Patrick Smith says...

02. Etc..
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So just add one to it! You are over thinking it.

Answer (score 3):

You obviously started at 0:

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach ...
```

If you wanted it to start at 1, you should code it to do so:

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach ...
```

One key to writing good code is *understanding* exactly what it is you're asking the computer to do.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to have `$i` start from one.

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>       

   <?php $ii = sprintf("%02d", $i);?>

   <?php $i++;echo $ii; echo '.&ensp;';?>
```